# Determining a winner from multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to determine group winners from points earned (firstly) then margins in Excel 2010.

In Column 1 there are 4 names, column 2 has points earned from wins and draws. If more than one of these are the maximum value, I then want to determine the winner of those, by the margins entered in the third column.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this formula:
`=INDEX(A2:A5,MAX(IF(B2:B5*10^5+C2:C5=MAX(B2:B5*10^5+C2:C5),ROW(B2:B5),""))-1)`

Where:

- `MAX(B2:B5*10^5+C2:C5)` calculates a weighted score, which considers column C only when values in column B are equal (`10^5` is just a random value, what's important is that minimum difference between scores after the multiplication should be bigger than maximum margin)
- `=MAX(IF(B2:B5*10^5+C2:C5=MAX(...),ROW(B2:B5),""))` - determines the row with the highest weighted score
- `=INDEX(A2:A5,MAX(...)-1)` - returns the team with the highest weighted score (`-1` is there for correction of the difference of scales (`INDEX` counts withing selected area, while row number is given from nested expression))

This is an array formula, so you need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after inserting it.

[image]